# Prevent WebView to scroll up when reload it

Tags: android, webview

I need to loadDataWithBaseURL many times but I don't want WebView scrolls up. How to do it? 
I guess I should cache the scrollbar position and restore it every time WebView finishs reloading but WebView doesn't have any methods like "setOnAfterLoadingListener".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` in `WebViewClient` although I don't know if it's triggered when reloading.